# Custom List Template not listed in web's ListTemplates

Tags: powershell, content-type, list-template

When viewing the List Template gallery I can see my custom (deployed via wsp) list template. I cannot see it when using powershell to display the web (sub web or root web)'s ListTemplates.

```
$web.ListTemplates["myTemplate"]
```

Returns null, for example.

Any reasons this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

To get custom list templates, use following script:

```
$site = Get-SPSite <YOURSITE>
$web = $site.AllWebs[0]
$listTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
```

Comment: I tried this and it actually returned nothing :( -- my only deviation was using $web.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($web) instead of creating an spsite object

Comment: Is your Custom List Template derived from one of default list templates like "Discussion Board"? Or it is derived from "Custom List" list template?

Comment: the parent content type is Item (0x01). sorry- i may have mis-phrased what this is- it's a content type (but it should be available in web.ListTemplates, no?)

Comment: What's so confusing to me is that I can see other custom content types in web.ListTemplates (via powershell) which have the same parent content type of 0x01 and same deployment procedures, etc..